# How do I delete a single calendar in Android (not just hide it)?

Tags: calendar, delete

How do I delete a single calendar from the native calendar app (not only the entries: the whole calendar) without wiping out the app or all calendars, in android >4.0?

This feature was available till ICS. In Kitkat, it's still not possible.

Comment: Why do you per se want to do it from your phone? No pc browser nearby? I guess you don't need to do this on a weekly basis?

Comment: I have to do it just a few times during development. How would a pc help? I am using a mac and the calendar appears just local on the phone.

Comment: Ah it's only a local Calendar? It's not synced? Then Chahk's answers makes no sense basically... My default Calendar app on Android 2.3 doesn't seem to support local calendars.

Answer (score 14):

I just ran into the same problem. I created a local calendar with an app and then removed the app before deleting the calendar. I could re-install the app and delete the calendar there. So, for you as a developer, this means you should probably add this functionality to your app.

However, if you need a quick fix or if someone else is running into this problem with a third-party app that does not provide a way to remove its own calendars, you can use the (no longer free) app [iCal Import/Export CalDAV](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=tk.drlue.icalimportexport.premium) by Lukas Aichbauer, as this app allows you to remove any local calendars.

Just start it, select "Edit Calendars", then "Choose Calendar", and select the calendar you want to remove. Then click "Delete Calendar" and confirm if you are certain you have selected the right one.

Maybe use the same app first to pull a backup of the calendars you want to keep.

Comment: Thank you very much! This was surprisingly hard to find. SolCalendar had created a calendar named "My Solcalendar" which remained after I had uninstalled the programme. Now I have been able to delete it. Incidentally, why doesn't Android itself have an interface to manage its calendars? Odd.

Comment: The app is offline, any other apps that would do that? Insane how google allows third party software to create local calendars that Google Calendar automatically set as default, but does not allow any means of removing it.

Answer (score 11):

Since it seems there is no easy free way to do this, I created my own =)

Here is the app: [Calendar Toolbox](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.whitebox.calendartoolbox)

If someone needs to create, delete, or update a local calendar, it will do it.

Comment: Awesome: Installed your toolbox, removed the default calender, uninstalled the toolbox. Thanks!

Comment: "App doesn't have permission to edit this calendar"... How to deal with that?

Comment: @Rune Look at what it says in the `Account name` field for that calendar. That might give you a hint. Try to log out of that account, or remove the app with that name, or something.

Comment: I found also ( in year 2022) , "Calendar account delete helper", which helpt me to delete  a calendar from already uninstalled app.

Answer (score 4):

Android devices have a local calendar storage database that is opaque and difficult to modify with app-level programmatic. You can, however, clear all local calendar data, which should remove the calendar entries permanently. Any sync'd calendars will repopulate.

Settings > Apps & Notifications > See all Apps > (... menu) Show System

Navigate to "Calendar Storage", choose "Storage & cache", and then "Clear storage".

All calendar events will disappear, sync'd events will repopulate via account sync over the next few minutes.

Another comment noted a paid app "CalDEV". My guess is that it does a less nuclear version of this.

Comment: In "See all Apps" there is a gigantic popup of all apps. Between these Apps, I can not see a "Show System", and it also does not look like an app name.

Answer (score 0):

[Calendar Backup](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=kfsoft.calendar.backup.ics) lets you backup and delete calendars. I just used it with the Samsung calendar on a Galaxy A6.

Before deleting it, you can export it as an .ics file as backup, and it offers you to save it or directly share it to an email or messaging account.